Can electrons be in the nucleus if electrons and protons swap masses?
Is is more stable for nucleus to be made of protons?
What if the mass of electron and proton were swapped? will then the nucleus be made of negatively charged particles?

There can't be nuclei that aren't made of stable hadrons, since only stable hadrons (made of color-charged quarks) are the only things that last long enough to get bound up by the nuclear force.
For one, the charges would remain the same as they are now (not that it makes a difference; why would they change?). The Bohr radius of the nucleus would go way down since the mass has gone way down; the wavelengths of the nuclei would also go way up since the mass has drastically decreased. In general I wouldn't think this system to be stable since the nuclei would have a much harder time attracting now-1800x-mass electrons to become bound to them. Without stable electron orbitals chemistry basically falls apart and everything above the quantum scale looks nothing like our own reality.
The two questions here ("is a proton [and neutron] nucleus more stable" and "will the nucleus then be made of negatively charged particles") have a definite "yes" and "no" answer, respectively. In the former case, protons and neutrons - the only stable hadrons - are the only building blocks for nuclei because they, made of quarks, are the only non-elementary particles that experience the nuclear force and also last long enough to form atoms and the like. In the latter case, of course not - a particle's charge has little to do with it's mass. In fact we could switch around the direction of charges (along with parity and time-direction) and reality would turn out exactly the same - this is known as CPT symmetry.
Now:

Can electrons be in the nucleus if electrons and protons swap masses

No. Electrons do not participate in strong interactions and would not be bound together in a nucleus.

Nice answer (+1) Since the proton has a natural neutral counterpart (the neutron), why doesn't the electron also have a natural neutral counterpart?

The neutron is a hadron, i.e. a composite particle, while the electron is elementary (specifically a lepton). The neutron, in fact, is just two down quarks and an up quark, and those quarks form their own little set of counterparts separate from the leptons; the closest you might get to an electrically-neutral electron is a neutrino of one generation or another, which is the "counterpart" of the electron/muon/tauon in the lepton family.

One might argue that the proton and neutron aren't "counterparts" at the fundamental level - they're just different arrangements of up quarks and down quarks (because that's what they are). Up quarks do have the natural counterpart of the down quark, and they have different charges.

thank you. To carry the analogy a bit further, a proton and a neutron can bind together to form a stable nucleus, how similar is this nucleus analogy to an electron and a photon binding together to form a stable "excited state"?

Well, I wouldn't exactly say that the photon survives that interaction (assuming we're talking about the same thing). That's the major difference; the photon's energy is transferred to the electron/atom in that interaction.

When a photon excites an atom, the photon's energy is transferred to the whole atom. It's not like the photon gets bound to the electron or the proton, it's "injected" into the EM field of the atom. And (of course) the EM field of the atom is just a region of the EM field that pervades the universe. It's not really a separate thing.

@PM2Ring are there heuristic patterns governing which atomic excited energy states is going to be stable or unstable, similar to which nucleus composition is going to be stable or unstable?

@James Atomic electron energy structure is a huge topic! But briefly, any isolated atom "wants" to return to the ground state, any excited state is only temporary. Wikipedia has some fairly extensive articles on this & related topics. I quite like these anims that illustrate various orbitals by simplifying spherical harmonics to a 2D "drum" surface. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Qualitative_understanding_of_shapes

If the electron were 2000 times more massive than the proton, then the electron would be nearly stationary at the center of the hydrogen atom and we’d call it “the nucleus”.

@Ghoster that's a good picture. Then what kind of structures should the protons and neutrons be forming around the "electrons nucleus", e.g. shells?

@James Yes, the lightweight proton would have the usual orbitals because the math would all be the same as you learn when you solve the Schrodinger equation for hydrogen.

@Ghoster thank you. Let's assume the electron excitation model is correct. Then what a photon does is essentially let itself be absorbed by an electron in order to increase the electron's "diameter" such that as many electrons can clump around the nucleus without violating Pauli exclusion, right? Using this model, a neutron would be allowing a proton to absorb it in order to pack as many protons stably while satisfying Pauli exclusion. Why then would the nucleus prefer roughly same number of protons and neutrons (e.g. $^{56}_{26}Fe$) instead of ever higher photon excitations used by electrons?
